# GeoServer data directory migration is not working?

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, migration

I have an Ubuntu server with a clean installation of Geoserver 2.5 and would like to migrate the data from an old Fedora server with Geoserver 2.2. I am following the instructions [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/migrating.html) and my steps are listed below.

The problem is that, although the Geoserver portal shows that my layers exist, attempting to use them or view them in a layer preview throws this error:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: 
Can't instantiate page using constructor public org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage()
```

As per the instructions above, my steps are:

- Copy data directory from old server
- copy in these files from the clean installation

  security/*.xml

  security/masterpw.*

  security/geoserver.jceks

  security/auth/*

  security/filter/*

  security/masterpw/*

  security/pwpolicy/*

  security/role/*

  security/usergroup/*
- rename security/users.properties to security/users.properties.old
- As the security/filter and security.config files were copied in from a clean 2.5 install, they are in the 2.5 format already
- Replace the data directory in my 2.5 install with the modified 2.2 data directory and set the owner to tomcat6
- restart tomcat
- log in to Geoserver and click "reload" against configuration and catalogues

Geoserver now shows all my layers in the "Layers" menu but I cannot render any of them as the above error is thrown.

Can anyone advise me where I have gone wrong?

Edit: as requested below, more of the error log

> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using
>   constructor public org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage() at
>   org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
>   at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329) at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436) at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545) at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:27)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:70)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:115)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:134)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:75)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:47)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:43)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:534) at
>   org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
>   ... 98 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.geoserver.ows.LocalWorkspaceCatalogFilter.hideResource(LocalWorkspaceCatalogFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.CatalogFilterAccessManager.hideResource(CatalogFilterAccessManager.java:95)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.CatalogFilterAccessManager.getAccessLimits(CatalogFilterAccessManager.java:49)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.buildWrapperPolicy(SecureCatalogImpl.java:793)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.checkAccess(SecureCatalogImpl.java:584)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.checkAccess(SecureCatalogImpl.java:478)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.checkAccess(SecureCatalogImpl.java:631)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.filterGroups(SecureCatalogImpl.java:946)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.getLayerGroups(SecureCatalogImpl.java:310)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AbstractFilteredCatalog.getLayerGroups(AbstractFilteredCatalog.java:248)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AbstractCatalogDecorator.getLayerGroups(AbstractCatalogDecorator.java:456)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.getLayerGroups(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:197)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.demo.PreviewLayerProvider.getItems(PreviewLayerProvider.java:69)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.fullSize(GeoServerDataProvider.java:236)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.updateMatched(GeoServerTablePanel.java:562)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.(GeoServerTablePanel.java:555)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.(GeoServerTablePanel.java:219)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.(GeoServerTablePanel.java:98)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage$1.(MapPreviewPage.java:63)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage.(MapPreviewPage.java:63)
>   ... 103 more

Comment: Can you share a larger portion of the logs from GeoServer?

Comment: @simogeo - sure, I've modified the question, above.

Comment: Problem with layergroups.....

Comment: sorry, did not mean to save the comment...

Anyway, this looks like a problem with layergroups (although the log is cut, next time put the log file as is somewhere where it can be downloaded).

May I suggest a different route? Use the original data directory and point the GeoServer 2.5 to it and let it try a direct upgrade.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @simogeo - you, sir, are a legend! It was the layer groups causing the problem. If I remove the xml files relating to the layer groups from the data directory, the server suddenly works fine. That points me in the right direction. Seems that perhaps 2.5 has a problem reading the layer groups config files from older versions...

Comment: LayerGroups have been _heavily_ reworked. Jumping from 2.2 to 2.5 might cause some headaches, although we have ironed out many issues about this in the past.

It might be worth sending an email on the GS mailing list with the full log attached.